# Sqlalchemy model instance from query / cursor results

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Is it possible to create sqlalchemy model instances having cursor data (I'm using postgresql so psycopg2 cursor).

Thing is I need to do some operations using cursor and later create model instances (based on existing records) so I could use orm layer to do something fancy about them.

I cannot find anything like that in documentation, has someone managed to do something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Query.instances()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.instances), but looks like it needs a ResultProxy instead of just raw cursor data. Might be something to work with.

```
result = engine.execute("select * from users")
for u in session.query(User).instances(result):
    print u
```